# Classloader issues: Exception not caught even if explicitly caught in test

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, osgi

This is the test scenario:

`Plugin A` has a utility Class `A.xyz()` that provides a method that throws a `java.util.NoSuchtElementException`

`Plugin B` provides "functionality".

`Fragment F` which uses `B` as host and provides tests for `B`.

Now, my JUnit test looks like this:

```
try {
    A.xyz(paramTriggeringNoSuchMethodException);
    fail('A.xyz did not throw NoSuchElementException');
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    // expected
}
```

So, I expect `A.xyz()` to throw `NoSuchElementException` and catch this exception excplicitly, but still the test fails telling me there was a `NoSuchtElementException` (which I just caught myself).

If I catch `Throwable` instead of `NoSuchElementException`, the test will pass.

How is that possible given that all plugins/fragments run in the same environment?
It seems that `A.xyz()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` which was loaded using a different `Classloader` as the test itself.

BTW: the test runs within Eclipse when started as a plugin test, but fails when run from maven using `mvn install`

Comment: So you are answering the question yourself. Two classes loaded by different `ClassLoader`s are always different classes, regardless of their name. However, having `java.util.NoSuchElementException` loaded by different class loaders is a bit strange. The JRE should normally forbid this.

Comment: @Holger: that is exactly the point: it is weird as it is a system exception coming from the JRE.

Comment: Wow: the following assertion at the beginning of the test fails: `assertNotNull("must not be null", NoSuchElementException.class.getClassLoader());`

Comment: That’s ok. A `null` `ClassLoader` implies the bootstrap loader which is correct for core Java classes. Now check what’s about the catched `Throwable` (also verify what actual class of the `Throwable` is; even if you are convinced that it must be `NoSuchElementException`, check twice…)

Comment: @Holger: the catched Throwable's classloader is not null: `org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@48dc0f[org.eclipse.swt:3.102.1.v20130827-2021(id=19)]`

Comment: But did you check the *type* of the `Throwable`? It could be a subclass of a JRE class which is allowed to be loaded by a different `ClassLoader`. Or, check the entire hierarchy like `for(Class<?> c=throwable.getClass(); c!=null; c=c.getSuperclass())
      System.out.println(c+" loaded by "+c.getClassLoader());`. Maybe it sheds some light on it.

Comment: Hm, you are right, it is an `SWTException`.

Comment: So it’s good to have unit tests :-)

Comment: I think the reason was that I was unaware of maven and eclipse having different states of the compiled classes. Whereas eclipse always used the latest sources, I would have to make sure to build the parent module of the test suite, before running it in maven. Thanks a lot, Holger. Your logical POV has helped here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen similar things happen when Maven in m2e gets behind. I would try the following things to fix the problem:

1. Right click Project -> Maven -> Update Project.
2. `mvn clean`, then try `mvn install` again.
3. If that didn't fix it, look at your import statements and make sure they are the correct classes.
4. If those don't fix the problem, actually check the output of `throwable.getClass().getName()` and `throwable.getClass().getClassLoader()` and see if they return the same output in both the Maven JUnit and Eclipse JUnit.

---

As an aside, why do you have a `try-catch` block in your JUnit test? I would instead do:

```
@Test(expected=NoSuchElementException.class) {
public void testNoSuchElement() {
    A.xyz(paramTriggeringNoSuchMethodException);
}
```

[Here's the javadoc on this parameter, `@Test.expected()`](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/Test.html#expected())

> ### expected
>
> `public abstract Class<? extends Throwable> expected`
>
> Optionally specify `expected`, a `Throwable`, to cause a test method to succeed iff an exception of the specified class is thrown by the method.
>
> **Default:**
>
> `org.junit.Test.None.class`

Comment: Thanks for the hint to @Test.expect. The code was a simplified scenario, in the real scenario, there are some more asserts before and after the assert in question. As for the issue itself: as the conversation with Holger reveals, the problem was at my side: maven compiled classes have not been in sync with the eclipse workspace.

Comment: @erdal.karaca the first part of my post should address that problem, I think.